# Angular-Cli: Different paths for Develop and Publish output

Tags: angular-cli

I have a "default" angular-cli setup. Can I build the `Develop` and `Publish` output in two different Folders/ Filenames? In the documantion, I only found the `outDir` property, but it applies for dev and prod build.

Can I somehow set this, e.g. in the environment.ts / environment.prod.ts.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It turns out you can override the default settings from your angular-cli.json by passing commandline arguments.

Example:

```
ng build --output-path \"RELEASEPATH"  --prod
```